# Publish as Azure Webjob is always forcing to Any CPU when publishing - even when set to x64

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

For an external library I *need* to build and run it on x64 configuration.

It seems to do this on every project despite the setting in the publish window. It does seem to honor the Release/Debug setting, but not the Platform setting.

How to proceed?

Comment: Could you share more info about your question? What did you mean "It does seem to honor the Release/Debug setting, but not the Platform setting."?

Comment: It always publishes on Any CPU, despite that you force in ont x64 in Publish Settings.

Comment: Hi George, thanks for your answer! I'm on a different project at the moment, but I'll put it on my list and come back to you - are you from the Azure team? Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

> It seems to do this on every project despite the setting in the
>   publish window.

The Any CPU won't change because It's a default platform(Like a name), and the any settings actually are changed. That's why your Debug Output always shows "Debug:Any CPU".

This setting could be change,

> Build->Configuration Manager->Project Platform->New

[image]
[image]

After these you go back to your Project Properties ->Build and click Platform x64 will be there. You could also switch them here.

[image]

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: Hi George, to already answer as far as I read this. I do have an x64 configuration/platform, but this setting seems to be ignored when I set it in Publish Settings. I'll add some images later. What I didn't try yet is actually taking Any CPU platform and setting all the projects on X64.